# ASP.NET & Ajax: query string parameters using ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, character-encoding, query-string

Here's another one for you to help me solve: I have an ASP.NET website that uses AJAX (asynchronous) calls to am `.ashx` handler, passing a *query string* parameter to get some information from the database.

Here's an example of how it works:

*Client-side* (Javascript) *code snippet* that makes the asynchronous call to the handler:

```
/* Capture selected value from a DropDownBox */
var dropdown = document.getElementById(DropDownID);
var selectedValue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

/* Make the call to the handler */
var url = "MyHandler.ashx?param=" + selectedValue;

var ajaxObj = new Ajax();
ajaxObj.doRequest(url, MyCallback, args, connectionFailed);
```

When I load the `webform` (that contains this AJAX call) for the first time, it sends the right query string to the handler (I checked it using debug in Visual Studio), like `param = Street Joseph Blíss`. That's the right behavior I want it to have.

The thing is that when I load that `webform` again (and all subsequent times), that `í` character from "Blíss" appears in server-side as `Ã­-`. As that's the key from the entity I'm trying to select on server-side database access script, it doesn't work as it worked on 1st `webform` load.

I tried encoding the *query string* on *client-side* and decoding it on *server-side*, using something like this:

*Client-side* (Javascript):

```
var encodedParam = encodeURIComponent(selectedValue);
/* Make the call to the handler */
var url = "MyHandler.ashx?param=" + encodedParam ;
```

*Server-side* (ASP.NET, C#):

```
string encodedParam = context.Request.QueryString["param"];
string value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedParam, Encoding.ASCII);
```

...but I had no luck with it and the problem still remains. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, I found out how to solve with *server-side* code refinement. Here's the deal:

I had to alter my .ashx handler to parse the original parameter grabbed from the *query string* and convert it into UTF-8. Here's how it's made:

```
// original parameterized value with invalid characters
string paramQs = context.Request.QueryString["param"];
// correct parsed value from query string parameter
string param = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1").GetBytes(paramQs));
```

Happy coding, folks! :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "iso-8859-1", as described here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.webname.aspx