# Asp.net Generic Handler Encoding Problem

Tags: asp.net, ajax, character-encoding

My problem is not too hard but really annoying.

I'm sending values to Generic Handler via Ajax like that way.

```
xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "AddMessage.ashx?" + (new Date().getTime()) +"&Message=" + Message,true);
```

when message contains İ,ç,ö,ğ,ü,ı they are looking like that on Handler �������
In context.Request.RawURL İ,ç,ö,ğ,ü,ı these characters are looking as it should. But in context.Request.Url they are looking like ������� and when i want QueryString values it gives me ������� what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. In `web.config` you've set UTF-8:

   ```
   <system.web>
       <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
       ...
   </system.web>
   ```
2. You've a proper meta tag in your HTML page:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   ```
3. All your `.aspx`, `.ascx`, `.master`, `.ashx`,... files are saved as UTF-8 with BOM on the hard drive.
4. You are properly URL encoding parameters before sending them (using the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:global_functions:encodeuricomponent) method):

   ```
   xmlHttpReq.open(
       "GET", 
       "AddMessage.ashx?" + 
           (new Date().getTime()) + 
           "&Message=" + encodeURIComponent(Message),
       true
   );
   ```

Comment: Thanks for quickly reply. But its not helping i'm already tried it. But i found the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578398/asp-net-ajax-query-string-parameters-using-iso-8859-1-encoding

Comment: Normally if you perform the 4 steps I suggested you, you won't need to do the conversions from the different encodings suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on this link.
[ASP.NET & Ajax: query string parameters using ISO-8859-1 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578398/asp-net-ajax-query-string-parameters-using-iso-8859-1-encoding)

```
// original parameterized value with invalid characters
string paramQs = context.Request.QueryString["param"];
// correct parsed value from query string parameter
string param = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1").GetBytes(paramQs));
```